# Formating and reinstaling OS on Galaxy S4

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4, unrooting, formatting

Someone put CyanogenMod on my T-Mobile Galaxy S4. So I tried to unroot and return to the original by watching [this Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEJSv9MrVAg) and using this method.This is what I have gotten from the phone:

```
Odin Mode
Product Name: SGH: M919
Current Binary: Custom
System Status: Custom
Knox Kernel Lock: 0X0
Knox Warranty Void: 0X1
Write protection: Enable
eMMC Bust: Mode: Enable
Start [224, 1440]                                           in red
SW REV. CHECK FAIL : fused : 4, Binary: 1 in red.
```

On the PC screen, in red, it says **Fail!**

In the message box, the last line read: All threads completed: (succeed 0 /  failed 1).

Now I tried to reboot the phone, I got the same Odin Mode thing plus: `CSB-CONFIG-LSB: 0X30` minus the two lines in red.

In the middle of the screen, a phone, a yellow triangle with an `!` mark in the center, a PC screen.

Below says: "Firmware upgrade encountered an issue. please select recovery mode in Kies & try again."

I have no phone now. I know I didnt reset binary flash. So people told me to format and reinstall the OS. Please help me to go back to stock version.

Comment: Have you tried flashing your phone with the latest ROM (for your country and carrier) via Odin Download Mode? Since you have already tripped Knox (Knox Warranty Void = 1), you can't flash pre-4.3 ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

- Get the stock ROM which works with root from sammobile.com. Make sure that Kies isn't running. Then, flash the ROM with Odin, **or**,
- Unroot using the custom recovery by downloading a completely stock normal ROM from sammobile which should get rid of root.

Answer (score 0):

Knox warranty void: `0x1`

You won't be able to flash a Knox enabled firmware anymore, but you can flash other firmware. Go to sammobile, search your firmware and flash it with Odin. You can also find the flashing tutorial from sammobile itself.

Remember: do not downgrade. This will damage your EFS folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go here [SamMobile Samsung GT-i9500](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s4/GT-I9500/)

Download the one specified for your country

Boot to Download Mode, 
Flash using Odin